# Среднее арифметическое элементов массива

Tags: c++

Написать программу, которая вычисляет среднее арифметическое элементов массива без учета минимального и максимального элементов массива. Ниже приведен рекомендуемый вид экрана во время работы программы, данные веденные пользователем выделены полужирным шрифтом.

Среднее арифметическое без учета min и max значений.
Введите массив (10 целых чисел в одной строке)

```
12 10 5 7 15 4 10 17 23 7
```

Минимальный элемент: 4

Максимальный элемент: 23

Среднее арифм. без учета min и max значений: 10.36

Comment: Уточните задачку, а что если встретится 2 и более одинаковых минимальных и максимальных значений? К примеру : 1, 2, 1, 3, 9, 8, 4, 9 ? Что нужно сделать? Вычесть сумму ВСЕХ минимальных или только одно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Даю алгоритм. Он до неприличия прост. На первом этапе находим минимальное и максимальное значение. На втором находим сумму остальных элементов. Далее эту сумму делим на общее число элементов - 2. Получаем искомое среднее. Нужные числа выводим на экран. Этого хватит для написания программы?

Answer (score 4):

А можно сделать за один проход. Для этого потребуется три переменная. Одна для суммы всех значений, вторая для хранения минимального, третья для максимального. Проходя по каждому элементу суммируем, сравнимаем на минимальность и максимальность. По достижению конца массива из суммы вычитаем минимальное и максимально, затем делим на ("кол-во элементов в массиве"-2)

Comment: По идее, надо хранить сумму _всех_ встреченных максимальных элементов. И минимальных. И их количество. И ещё проверить, не равен ли минимальный элемент максимальному.

Comment: Вот вам (или кому-то) кажется, что за один проход эффективнее, чем за два, а на самом деле нет, потому что накладные расходы на счетчик цикла крайне малы. Я часто вижу людей, которые хотят сложное запихнуть в один цикл, когда проще и понятнее сделать несколько. Особенно со вложенными циклами так. Не мелочитесь.

Comment: @Zelta: У однопроходного решения есть преимущество. Например, если данных так много, что они не помещаются в память, и мы читаем их последовательно с диска. На 10 элементах (и вообще, < 10000) разницы, конечно, нет, и сделать код понятнее гораздо важнее.

Comment: @VladD: Ну skegg тоже понял задачу также как и я, поэтому и написал свое решение с поиском одного минимального и максимального. Но задан уточняющий вопрос, может автор улучшит вопрос ;)

Comment: @sys_dev: В 2011 году меня ещё не было на сайте :) А то я бы и в том ответе переспросил.

Comment: @VladD: А я повелся )))) Увидел, что вопрос на главной странице и тут же ответил :)